# Use Rclone for backup Seafile in Azure Blob

Tags: azure-blob-storage, rclone, seafile-server

I am noob in Rclone, so here is my question:

I have a raspberry Pi with Seafile working fine. I would like to install Rclone there to backup the content of the Seafile to an Azure storage blob. I saw in the documentation that Rclone supports both Seafile and Azure blob, but I've no idea if it is possible to configure the scenario at the same time.

Can you advise?

Thanks